# Get total amount of days for the month between 2 dates grouped by month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a booking system for hotel rooms, sometimes there are reservations that start in one month and finish in another month. For example 22 April 2019 to 07 May 2019.

I need to be able to see how many days the room was booked in April.

Can't figure out how to reduce the overlapping days in the next month.

So if I have those bookings:

```
07/Apr/2019 to 12/Apr/2019
22/Apr/2019 to 07/May/2019
29/May/2019 to 03/June/2019
```

It should give me:

April 2019: 13 Days
May 2019: 10 Days
June 2019: 3 Days

I tried using `DATEDIFF` and `SUM` but it adds MAY Dates also.

```
$sql = "SELECT 
id, SUM(DATEDIFF(booking_to, transaction_date)) + 1 AS occup,
COALESCE(COUNT(id), 0) AS `transactions`,
COALESCE(SUM(revenue), 0) AS `revenue`
FROM transactions
WHERE property_id = $pvid
AND MONTH(transaction_date) = $tranmonth 
AND YEAR(transaction_date) = $tranyear
group by property_id";
```

Currently it is giving me 20 Days which is incorrect.

Is it possible to the amount of days booked only for April?

Answer (score 0):

what you probably need is the last day of the month and **diff** it after

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(NOW());
```

edit:

```
     select now() as now, timestampdiff(day, now(), last_day(now())) as diff;
+---------------------+------+
| now                 | diff |
+---------------------+------+
| 2019-05-04 05:48:43 |   26 |
+---------------------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the issue now is that it is counting days from from the next month also. I need it to calculate how many days per month only.

Comment: the method above counts the days from today until the end of the month.
change it to whatever makes sense to you `select now() as now, timestampdiff(day, '2019-05-22 15:20:12', last_day('2019-05-22 15:20:12')) as diff;`

Comment: Thanks anyway that did not solve my issue. I found a solution here
[link](https://www.jdhodges.com/blog/count-total-reservation-occupancy-rate-mysql/) He shows how to do it and get the right amount of days.
Thanks